# How to specify project's custom xcconfig with debug configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I set my project with 6 custom xcconfigs like the image displayed:
[My project xcconfig setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J0re.jpg)

And in each custom xcconfig file, I included corresponding pods-generated-xcconfig like following code:

```
 #include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-GameCenter/Pods-GameCenter.dev-debug.xcconfig"
YPW_APP_BUNDLE_ID = com.netease.gamecenterDev
YPW_APP_DISPLAY_NAME = 游品位-Dev
```

What I confused is that **Cocoapod seems to regard all my custom xcconfig as release mode** like this:[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdN1k.jpg), and you can also see Cocoapods still generated Debug and Release xcconfig even I haven't use it.

Also I have found that **some configurations in Pod project is not same as Debug and Release**,like **Build Products Path**

So how can I  specify some of my custom xcconfigs to debug mode（I want my "DEV-Debug" config's **Build Active Architecture Only** option to YES） , and how to let the pod config the configuration like its Debug/Release mode

Thanks a lot if you can provide any help.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the type(Debug or Release) of each custom configuration, add this to your project's Podfile:

```
project 'GameCenter', {
    'Debug' => :debug,
    'DEv-Debug' => :debug,
    'AdHoc-HK' => :release,
    'AdHoc-SC' => :release,
    'AdHoc-HK' => :release,
    'AdHoc-SC' => :release,
    'DEv-Release' => :release,
    'Release' => :release,
}
```